# Cannot convert list in Excel Power Query Editor

Tags: json, excel, powerquery

I am trying to convert JSON API response into a table in Excel using the Power Query functionality.  I am currently getting the error below when I try to put the customerOrderHistory which is a list into a delimited list as I don't want to create extra rows for a list if I can avoid it.

[image]

If possible I would like to either

- Just print the customerOrderHistory list in the JSON format that it is in already into the cell
  OR
- Create a delimited list of the values as the lists only contain one entry at the moment

The JSON test file looks like this:

```
{
    "computerid": "1",
    "total": 1,
    "results": [
        {
            "computerid": "1",
            "customerOrderHistory": [
                {
                    "orderId": "1",
                    "channelId": null,
                    "agentId": null,
                    "orderItems": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You should post whatever code you are using to try to create your delimited list. Whatever you are doing is looking for a list, but you are supplying a record. You can convert a record to a list using Record.ToList or Record.FieldValues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Json.FromValue` to convert the list into a Binary value, and then use `Text.FromBinary` to get back the string representation. If you can dig down deep enough to get to the `customerOrderHistory` field it would look like `Text.FromBinary(Json.FromValue(result[customerOrderHistory]))`.